# Random signal 11 (SIGSEGV)

Tags: android, kotlin, segmentation-fault

For few days now i got SIGSEGV errors at random points in my app. It crashed when i do nothing.

I started taking apart code to see which line was causing this segmentation, and was most shocked when i found out that it was: ( drum roll, please )

`Activity.setResult(Activity.OK,intent)`

WHAT? This still doesn't make ANY sense to me at all! In the line below i will show you my code before and after and can anyone tell me WHY the SIGSEGV was happening?

**Before**

CommentActivity:

```
val comments = ArrayList<Comment>()
comments.add(comment)
/*Set the results*/
val intent = Intent()
intent.putExtra("comment_result", Utils.General.serializeToJson(comments))
this.setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent)
this.finish()
```

MainActivity:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        //catch data from CommentActivity
        case (INTENT_COMMENT): {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                String comments = intent.getExtras().getString("comment_result");
                if (comments != null && !comments.isEmpty()) {
                    /*Save the instance to the database and expect the database observable to call the upload thread*/
                    Type type = new TypeToken<ArrayList<Comment>>() {}.getType();
                    ArrayList<Comment> list = Utils.General.Companion.deserializeFromJson(comments, type);
                    /*Save the instance to the database and expect the database observable to call the upload thread*/
                    DataSource.INSTANCE.saveComments(list);
                } else {
                    showToast(getResources().getString(R.string.picture_lost), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                }
            }
            break;
        }
```

==== This crashed in MainActivity after between 10secs and 1 minute =====

**After - No Crash**

CommentActivity:

```
/*Set the results*/
DataSource.saveComments(comments)
this.finish()
```

Comment: You try to [disable Instant Run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C902z.jpg) and rebuild your app

Comment: Made that mistake earlier in my dev days. Instant run is always disabled!